# Crawling data and shows stored data with APIFY

Tags: apify

I have scraped a website and it shows that the operation succeeded, but nothing gets displayed. It tells me, that the result in the data-set is empty.

Comment: Hi, it helps a lot if you add your code (or a minimal version of it, so other people can try it). Also what you were expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your page function failed or you were blocked or the data is loaded dynamically later. It is hard to give advice when we don't know the details.

The SUCCEEDED status doesn't mean all or any URLs were actually scraped, it just means there wasn't any hard crash in the code itself. So I would not concern with this status and focus on if the data you need is actually in the dataset. If you open the un-clean dataset, you may see error messages there explaining if something went wrong.